# Twitter and Oauth results in 401 error

Tags: oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using Oauth to connect to Twitter, but it results in a 401 error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
//config
define('CONSUMER_KEY',"");
define('CONSUMER_SECRET',"");
define('OAUTH_TOKEN',"1U");
define('OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET',"");

require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');

$connection = new TwitterOAuth (CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);

$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'testing'));

$httpc = $connection->http_code;
if($httpc == 200) {
echo 'succesvol';
} else {

echo $httpc;
}
```

Comment: What error message is Twitter returning?

Answer (score 4):

You get a `401 (Not Authorised)` error when you do not provide the correct `ConsumerKey` and `ConsumerSecret` values.

Looking at the code above, you are passing empty string values for those two variables. Unless you left them out on purpose, you need to double check your values.

For my app, this is where they exist.

(ASSUMPTION: you've created a Twitter application @ [dev.twitter.com](http://dev.twitter.com))

[image]

Comment: +1 lol i think the OP might find the field thanks to your little arrow